# Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 11

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, dart

After adding Firebase product packages to my Flutter project the iOS version of my App can't run. I have searched on the internet and tried many solutions but still the problem persist.

**This is the error message I get:**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode... Running Xcode build... Xcode build done.                                          
38.9s Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output: ↳
    In file included from /Users/currentUser/Projects/Flutter/myapp/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/tls_credentials_options_util.cc:19:
    In file included from /Users/currentUser/Projects/Flutter/myapp/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/tls_credentials_options_util.h:25:
    In file included from /Users/currentUser/Projects/Flutter/myapp/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/credentials/tls/grpc_tls_credentials_options.h:28:
    In file included from /Users/currentUser/Projects/Flutter/myapp/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_utils.h:33:
    In file included from /Users/currentUser/Projects/Flutter/myapp/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/security_connector.h:33:
    /Users/currentUser/Projects/Flutter/myapp/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.h:28:10: fatal error: 'openssl/x509.h' file not found
    #include <openssl/x509.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Comment: Have you used same version in PodFile as well as in xCode ?

Comment: Please version of what are you referring to? @ShubhamNarkhede

Comment: This is the link to the [project](https://github.com/Kakyire/chatapp)